# Invalid Operation Exception when trying to get decimal value from SQL into double

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.2

I have a SQL table which has several large decimal values in them.  Too large to use `decimals` in my model.  However when I use `double` I get an `Invalid Operation Exception` which states that it was unable to convert `System.Decimal` to `System.Double`.

I'm using EntityFramework Core in a .Net Core 2.2 application.  Is there a way to specify to my DbContext that it should grab these fields as doubles instead of decimals?

I am using a Microsoft SQL Server database.  My column type is decimal(38, 2).  The value that's stored there is ~ 1.0005e+35.  I know that this value is too big to fit into a C# `Decimal` so I need to fit it into a `System.Double` instead.

Comment: Have you tried setting the type during mapping? `modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Property(d => d.MyDouble).ForSqlServerHasColumnType("decimal(38, 2)");`

Comment: @mxmissile Yes. It still gave the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  Apparently EF Core designates the different SQL types directly to C# types.  So a SQL `decimal` maps to a C# `Decimal`.  A SQL `float` maps to a C# `System.Double`. And a SQL `real` maps to a C# `System.Float`.

So the solution to my issue was to change the `decimal(38,2)` to a `float` in my SQL table

Comment: Just a friendly heads up, be aware of the differences between `decimal` and a `float`. Float uses "approximate" precision. Decimal is fixed precision. They are *not* the same, and might produce undesirable results.

Comment: Yes i realize that.  For these fields the precision is not important. They're just large numbers